# WeIrD StRiNg CaSe codewars

Tags: c#, алгоритм, строки

Появилась проблема при решении [данной задачи](https://www.codewars.com/kata/52b757663a95b11b3d00062d/train/csharp) на codewars c#. Суть задачи заключается в принятии строки и возвращении той же строки со всеми четными индексированными символами в каждом слове в верхнем регистре и всеми нечетными в нижнем регистре. К примеру:

```
1)Input: "This"
  Output:"ThIs"

2)Input: "This is a test"
  Output: "ThIs Is A TeSt"
```

Код проходит все базовые тесты, но как только дело доходит до доп. тестов он резко начинает будто сходить с ума и поднимать всё, что попадётся на его пути , пример:

```
№1
Input: "Ecmkjc y fjbhxtfd yavhpb c i abh ftg"
Ожидается:"EcMkJc Y FjBhXtFd YaVhPb C I AbH FtG"
Вывод кода: "ECMKJC Y FjBHXTFD YaVhPB C I AbH FTG"

№2
Input: "Wauf qa lakuz z ooehf pg yb fds ydf rz qye"
Ожидается:"WaUf Qa LaKuZ Z OoEhF Pg Yb FdS YdF Rz QyE"
Ragemod моего кода:"WaUf Qa LaKUZ Z OOEHF Pg Yb FdS YdF RZ QYE"
```

Сам код(проверял даже на бумаге, честно говоря ошибки не нашёл):

```cs
using System;

public class Kata
{
  public static string ToWeirdCase(string s)
  {
  char[] arr = s.ToCharArray(); 
  for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i += 2)
  {
    if (arr[i] != ' ')
      {  
        arr[i] = char.ToUpper(arr[i]); 
      }
    else
      {
        i -= 1;      
      }
  }
  return new string(arr); ; 
  }
}
```

Comment: зачем нужно вот это `i -= 1; ` и где у вас приведение в нижний регистр?

Comment: `new string ("some_text".Select((c, i) => i % 2 == 0 ? char.ToUpper(c) : char.ToLower(c)).ToArray());` ?

Comment: @tym32167, при использовании вашего метода выходит исключение ```error CS1061: 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Select'```

Comment: `using System.Linq;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Слишком много мудрите. Вот простой и понятный вариант

```
public static string ToWeirdCase(string s)
{
    char[] arr = s.ToCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
            arr[i] = char.ToUpper(arr[i]);
        else
            arr[i] = char.ToLower(arr[i]);
    }
    return new string(arr); ;
}
```

Если каждое слово начинать с большой буквы, можно изобразить алгоритм, где каждое слово обрабатывается отдельно, например

```
public static string ToWeirdCase(string s)
{
    char[] arr = s.ToCharArray();
    int index = 0;      
    while (index < arr.Length)
    {
        // пропускаем всё, что не буквы
        while (index < arr.Length && !char.IsLetter(arr[index]))
            index++;
            
        // обработка слова
        int counter = 0;            
        while (index < arr.Length && char.IsLetter(arr[index]))
        {
            if (counter % 2 == 0)
                arr[index] = char.ToUpper(arr[index]);
            else
                arr[index] = char.ToLower(arr[index]);
            index++;
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return new string(arr);
}
```

Comment: Если судить по тем данным, что предоставил автор, то там отсчет четности идет для каждого слова отдельно, вот поэтому он и мудрит код, пытаясь отсечь пробелы)

Comment: ну заведи ещё один счётчик, который обнуляется на пробелах)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ ок ок, добавил вариант с отдельным счетчиком.

Answer (score 2):

В копилку, моя версия с использованием `StringBuilder`.

```cs
public static string ToWeirdCase(string s)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    bool state = true;
    foreach (char c in s)
    {
        if (char.IsLetter(c))
        {
            sb.Append(state ? char.ToUpper(c) : char.ToLower(c));
            state = !state;
        }
        else
        {
            sb.Append(c);
            state = true;
        }
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо всем за комментарии и советы, @tym32167 ваш способ рабочий(огромное спасибо), я опубликую собственное решение (до которого мне помогла додуматься 3-я чашка кофе), которое чуть больше будет понятно новичку, нежели тернарный оператор, да простят меня Стив Макконнелл "Совершенный код" и Боб Мартин "Чистый код"

```cs
public class Kata
{
    public static string ToWeirdCase(string s)
    {
        char[] arr = s.ToCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i += 2)
        {
            if (arr[i] != ' ')
            {
                if (s.Length - i == 1)
                {
                    arr[i] = char.ToUpper(arr[i]);
                }
                else
                {
                    arr[i] = char.ToUpper(arr[i]);
                    arr[i + 1] = char.ToLower(arr[i + 1]);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                i -= 1;
            }
        }
        return new string(arr); ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Если вам нужно обработать каждый символ, почему шаг цикла 2? Зачем эти отшагивания перед пробелами?

Comment: Слишком страшное форматирование кода для ответа, читать невозможно. Отформатируйте пожалуйста код с нормальными отступами.

Comment: @aepot Предложите правку к моему ответу , я новичок в c# и не совсем знаю "каноны" оформления кода

Comment: @shalor1k ок, поправил

Comment: @aepot Спасибо, буду знать